# Inherit from VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, uiviewcontroller

I can not inherit from VC. I have error   Cannot find interface declaration for 'FeedViewController', superclass of 'FeedDetailViewController'; did you mean 'MenuViewController'

I have interface.

```
 @interface FeedViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, REFrostedViewControllerDelegate>

 @property (nonatomic) LoginType *loginType;
 - (id)initWithLoginType:(LoginType *)loginType;
 @end



 @interface FeedViewController () 
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataSource;
 .,..
  @end
```

Forward reference make this error:    Attempting to use the forward class 'FeedViewController' as superclass of 'FeedDetailViewController'

If I am tring to make property in this class (for test) I have error:   Unknown type name 'FeedViewController'; did you mean 'MenuViewController'?

So, compiler  can not find this class, I can not help him with forward reference.

What happens here?

Comment: Could you give us declare : FeedDetailViewController, FeedViewController? I think you have problem with declare these classes

Answer (score 0):

If you use a class in a header file, normally people will say "use a forward declaration".  However, this advice does not apply when creating subclasses.

The header file that declares the interface for `FeedDetailViewController` needs to `#import` the header for `FeedViewController`

Comment: @user3540499 Are the two classes in different headers?